# Proof - Subsets of disjoint open sets are separated

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of **R**. Show that if there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ with $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$, then $A$ and $B$ are separated.

**Proof:**
We will first show that $U$ and $V$ are separated by contradiction. Assume the two sets are not separated, then (without loss of generality) $\overline{U}\cap V$ is nonempty. Take L to be the set of limit points of $U$, since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint but $\overline{U}\cap V=(U\cup L)\cap V=(V\cap U)\cup(V\cap L)=\emptyset\cup(V\cap L)=V\cap L\neq\emptyset$, there must exist some element $a\in L,a\in V$. Because $a$ is a limit point of $U$, we know that every $V_\epsilon(a)$ intersects U at some point other than $a$. We also know that V is an open set with $a\in V$, which means that there exists an $V_{\epsilon_1}(a)\subseteq V$. However, we also know that there exists some point $V_\epsilon(a),b\in V_{\epsilon_1}(a)\rightarrow b\in V,b\in U\rightarrow V\cap U\neq\emptyset$. However, this contradicts our original assumption that V and U are disjoint, which means V and U must be separated sets.

Now to prove that $A$ and $B$ are separated. We know that (without loss of generality) $U\cap\overline{V}=\emptyset$, and that if L is a subset of limit points, $B\cup L_B\subset V\cup L_V\rightarrow \overline{B}\subseteq\overline{V}$, taken together with the fact that $A\subseteq U$, we get that $A\cup\overline{B}\subseteq U\cup\overline{V}=\emptyset\rightarrow A\cup\overline{B}=\emptyset$, thus A and B are separated.

I think this proof is complete and correct but I just want to make sure. I also know I took  $B\cup L_B\subset V\cup L_V\rightarrow \overline{B}\subseteq\overline{V}$ without proof but I'm not too sure how to go about proving that.

Answer (score 1):

You've far overcomplicated the proof. It's as simple as this.

$A\cap\overline B\subset U\cap \overline V=\varnothing$, where the equality holds because $$\overline V=\bigcap\limits_{C\text{ open}\\V\cap C=\varnothing}\mathbb R\setminus C\subset\mathbb R\setminus U$$A parallel argument shows that $\overline A\cap B=\varnothing$. Thus, $A,B$ are separated.